# memit and timeit at the same time

Tags: python, profiling, ipython

Can I `%memit` and `%timeit` an IPython cell at the same time?
How many times will it run then in case below?

```
%memit -r 3
%timeit -r 2
my_awesome_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried some combinations in Jupyter, ended up using `%%time` on cell level and `%memit` on line level:

```
%%time
d = 64                           
nb = 1000000                      
nq = 10000                       

%memit xb = np.random.random((nb, d))

%memit xq = np.random.random((nq, d))

time.sleep(5)
```

which outputs:

```
peak memory: 1252.40 MiB, increment: 457.10 MiB
peak memory: 797.77 MiB, increment: 2.48 MiB
CPU times: user 866 ms, sys: 230 ms, total: 1.1 s
Wall time: 6.34 s
```